# Detecting SSL certificates due for expiry

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have *.cer files that are a part of a project that reside on my local disk. They are not installed in my system.

Say the location of certs is: C:\Users\wrick\Source\Repos\MyProject\Src\Certificates\

Now I want to run a PowerShell script that will give me the list of *.cer files that are due for expiry in 90 days.

This is what I wrote:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\Users\wrick\Source\Repos\MyProject\Src\Certificates\ |
    Select-Object -Property PSChildName, Subject,
        @{n=’ExpireInDays’;e={($_.notafter – (Get-Date)).Days}} |
    Where-Object {$_.ExpireInDays -lt 90 -and $_.Extension -like "*.cer"}
```

I have added the `$_.Extension -like "*.cer"` part because the cert directory has some other script files too. 
I am not getting any output when I run this script.

Comment: I think you only get the `notafter` property when doing `gci` on `Cert:\ ` . Not on `.cer` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do this in powershell, just dip into the .Net framwork and use the [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
#Filter for *.cer files as early as possible
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\Users\wrick\Source\Repos\MyProject\Src\Certificates\ -Filter *.cer |
#grab the full file path, read in the cert, get the expiration date and convert to a datetime object
select FullName,@{name='ExpirationDate';e={[DateTime]([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile($_.FullName).GetExpirationDateString())}} |
#filter for those that expire within 90 days
Where-Object {$_.ExpirationDate -lt [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(90)}
```