# get certificate expiration date powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to get your ideas how would you get the remaining days for a certificate to expire.

I need to "monitor" a specific certificate expiration and I'd like it to notify (email) for 30 days before it expires till it's renewed.

I can look for the cert by running:

```
$cert = "AAAAAAAEEEEEEEFIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOOUUUUUUUU"
Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse | where {$_.Thumbprint -eq $cert}
```

but how could I get the remaining days if is below 30?

Any comment or help is always appreciated.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse | where {$_.Thumbprint -eq $cert} | foreach { ($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).TotalDays; }`. If you need the start of the current day `Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601479/detecting-ssl-certificates-due-for-expiry has some relevant code

Comment: Great article which explains how to check expiring certs: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-certificates-that-are-about-to-expire/

Answer (score 7):

Fixitrod gives the right answer. But if somehow you want to know the exactly date that will expire, you can run the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object NotAfter, Subject
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, i slightly modified the last command to below so i can get more info and format it in list view

```
get-childitem -path cert: -recurse -Expiringindays 30 | Select-Object Issuer, NotAfter, Subject, FriendlyName | FL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem -path cert: -recurse -Expiringindays 30
```

Comment: So I understand this is the correct answer, but if I want to get ONLY certificates that are still valid, I am using below. Is this the correct way? Or is there another way? 

` (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:CurrentUser\\MY -CodeSigningCert -recurse -Expiringindays 366 | Where-Object {$_.Subject -Match "$MySubjectName"})`